# multiple values for optarg

Tags: c, argv, argc

I want to be able to get 2 values for -a arg like: -a min max

I have the following code:

```
while((opt = getopt(argc,argv,"a:c:k:rv")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
         case 'a':
                min = atoi(optarg);
                fprintf( stderr,"value1: %s\n", optarg);
                optind--;
                for( ;optind < argc && *argv[optind] != '-'; optind++)
                {
                    optind++;
                    fprintf( stderr,"value2: %s\n", optarg);
                    max = atoi(optarg);
                }
            break;
          //other cases
     }
}
```

***How can I get multiple values for a single argument?***

Comment: You would need to modify `getopt`. Adopting syntax like `-a min:max` would be much easier.

Comment: will this affect my other args syntax ?

Comment: No it won't, why should it? You of course need to parse it yourself but this is very easy with e g. `strtok`.

Comment: is there any other way? I don't like using strtok

Comment: `sscanf(optarg, "%d:%d", &min, &max)` should also work. If you don't like it, use `strtol` and check the remainder string.

Comment: thank you, sscanf worked. Please post it as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to accept two parameters of an option is to join them with a non-blank character like `':'`:

```
myprogram -a min:max other-options
```

This way `getopt` thinks of it as of a single parameter. When you handle it you need to separate it in two yourself. If both halves are numbers, then this should work:

```
if (sscanf(optarg, "%d:%d", &min, &max) != 2)
  /* report an error */
```